# How I can fixed build in installing php 7.4?

Tags: php, openssl

I try to install php 7.4 in command `phpbrew install 7.4`, but build is failed
I try to reinstall openssl, reinstall libraries and all links about this problem in google.

build log:

```
===> phpbrew will now build 7.4.25
You haven't enabled any variants. The default variant will be enabled:
[bcmath, bz2, calendar, cli, ctype, dom, fileinfo, filter, ipc, json, mbregex, mbstring, mhash, pcntl, pcre, pdo, pear, phar, posix, readline, sockets, tokenizer, xml, curl, openssl, zip]
Please run 'phpbrew variants' for more information.

===> Loading and resolving variants...
Checking distribution checksum...
Checksum matched: 27992570caf3e2e5323ab7b37853c44c1529b1d31ea94d9776efa91d5a781313
===> Distribution file was successfully extracted, skipping...
Found existing Makefile, running make clean to ensure everything will be rebuilt.
You can append --no-clean option after the install command if you don't want to rebuild.
===> Running make clean: /usr/bin/make -C '/Users/i.pishchylin/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.25' --quiet 'clean'
===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for replace apache php module name with custom version name
Checking patch for replace freetype-config with pkg-config on php older than 7.4
Found existing build.log, renaming it to /Users/i.pishchylin/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.25/build.log.1635245534
===> Configuring 7.4.25...


Use tail command to see what's going on:
   $ tail -F '/Users/i.pishchylin/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.25/build.log'


===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for php5.3.x on 64bit machine when intl is enabled.
Checking patch for openssl dso linking patch
2 changes patched.
Checking patch for php5.6 with openssl 1.1.x patch.
===> Building...
Error: Make failed:
The last 5 lines in the log file:
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.0_1/include/openssl/rsa.h:289:29: note: passing argument to parameter 'rsa' here

                       RSA *rsa, int padding);

                            ^

108 warnings and 1 error generated.

make: *** [ext/openssl/openssl.lo] Error 1

Please checkout the build log file for more details:
     tail /Users/i.pishchylin/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.25/build.log
```

tail /Users/i.pishchylin/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.25/build.log:

```
#     define OSSL_DEPRECATED(since) __attribute__((deprecated))
                                                   ^
/Users/i.pishchylin/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.25/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5960:6: warning: passing 'const struct rsa_st *' to parameter of type 'RSA *' (aka 'struct rsa_st *') discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
                                        EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA(pkey),
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.0_1/include/openssl/rsa.h:289:29: note: passing argument to parameter 'rsa' here
                       RSA *rsa, int padding);
                            ^
108 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [ext/openssl/openssl.lo] Error 1
```

I try install with openssl@1.1, but it version is too old. How i can fixed this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and solved it by overwriting the OPENSSL_* environment variables based on my preinstalled openssl (v1.1):

```
OPENSSL_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include" \
OPENSSL_LIBS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -lcrypto -lssl" \
phpbrew install 7.4.20 +default
```

You might have to remove openssl v3.0 first.

Kudos to jrmgx: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/1249#issuecomment-929169315