# How can I fix this build in installing php 7.4.6 on mac?

Tags: php

I need to install php7.6.4 and I'm having problems.
First I installed all the necessary modules.

```
% brew install openssl
% brew install libxml2
% brew install pkg-config
% brew install BZip2
```

next I tried to install php7.4.6, then the following happened.

```
walewilliam@ueruuiriamunoMacBook-Air ~ % phpbrew install 7.4.6 +default
PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property PhpBrew\Console::$loader is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/vendor/corneltek/cliframework/src/Application.php on line 117

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property PhpBrew\Console::$loader is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/vendor/corneltek/cliframework/src/Application.php on line 117
PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property CLIFramework\ArgInfo::$desc is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/vendor/corneltek/cliframework/src/ArgInfo.php on line 38

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CLIFramework\ArgInfo::$desc is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/vendor/corneltek/cliframework/src/ArgInfo.php on line 38
PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property CLIFramework\ArgInfo::$desc is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/vendor/corneltek/cliframework/src/ArgInfo.php on line 38

Deprecated: Creation of dynamic property CLIFramework\ArgInfo::$desc is deprecated in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpbrew/vendor/corneltek/cliframework/src/ArgInfo.php on line 38
===> phpbrew will now build 7.4.6
===> Loading and resolving variants...
Homebrew prefix "/opt/homebrew/opt/mhash" does not exist.
Checking distribution checksum...
Checksum matched: a6ed9475695d2056322a3f2c00fee61a122a7fce138a0e25694320c5dd1d2348
===> Distribution file was successfully extracted, skipping...
Found existing Makefile, running make clean to ensure everything will be rebuilt.
You can append --no-clean option after the install command if you don't want to rebuild.
===> Running make clean: /usr/bin/make -C '/Users/walewilliam/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.6' --quiet 'clean'
Running make clean to ensure everything will be rebuilt.
===> Running make clean: /usr/bin/make -C '/Users/walewilliam/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.6' --quiet 'clean'
===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for replace apache php module name with custom version name
Checking patch for replace freetype-config with pkg-config on php older than 7.4
Checking patch for fix readline detection on PHP 5.3 to PHP 7.1
---> Applying patch...
patching file 'ext/readline/config.m4'
2 out of 2 hunks failed--saving rejects to 'ext/readline/config.m4.rej'

Patch failed
0 changes patched.
Found existing build.log, renaming it to /Users/walewilliam/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.6/build.log.1680586418
===> Configuring 7.4.6...


Use tail command to see what's going on:
   $ tail -F '/Users/walewilliam/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.6/build.log'


===> Checking patches...
Checking patch for php5.3.x on 64bit machine when intl is enabled.
Checking patch for openssl dso linking patch
0 changes patched.
Checking patch for php5.6 with openssl 1.1.x patch.
===> Building...
Error: Make failed:
The last 5 lines in the log file:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.0/include/openssl/rsa.h:295:29: note: passing argument to parameter 'rsa' here

                       RSA *rsa, int padding);

                            ^

107 warnings and 1 error generated.

make: *** [ext/openssl/openssl.lo] Error 1

Please checkout the build log file for more details:
     tail /Users/walewilliam/.phpbrew/build/php-7.4.6/build.log
```

After looking up the error above, I found [this wonderful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722049/how-i-can-fixed-build-in-installing-php-7-4) and tried it.

I uninstalled openssl@3 and ran the following command,

```
OPENSSL_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include" \
OPENSSL_LIBS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -lcrypto -lssl" \
phpbrew install 7.4.6 +default
```

then the following error came up.

```
Error: Configure failed:
The last 5 lines in the log file:
checking for ZLIB support... no

checking whether to enable bc style precision math functions... yes

checking for BZip2 support... yes

checking for BZ2_bzerror in -lbz2... no

configure: error: bz2 module requires libbz2 >= 1.0.0
```

I can't find how to install any of the "BZ2_bzerror", "-lbz2", "bz2", or "libbz2".
How do I fix this error?